# InnoDB: Is a covering index in the form of (PK, col1, col2, col3) redundant?

Tags: mysql, innodb, clustered-index

Table structure for table `config`:

- property (primary key)
- value
- description

Query:

```
SELECT property, value FROM config
```

If I put a covering index on `(property, value)` the optimizer still chooses the `PRIMARY` index, but the `extra` in `EXPLAIN` is `NULL`. If I tell the optimizer to use my covering index, the `extra` in `EXPLAIN` is `USING INDEX`.

What's really happening here? Why is the optimizer choosing the `PRIMARY` index over my covering index by default? Am I avoiding disk IO by telling the optimizer to use my covering index?

Comment: You don't need an index if you select ALL the records of a table. Indexes come in handy for instance when using a `where` clause. A rule of thumb is to define indexes for all columns that are used in `where` clauses.

Comment: My goal in using a covering index is to have the data retrieved from memory rather than from disk. Where I'm confused is whether or not disk IO is occurring when I let the optimizer use its choice of the PK over my covering index.

Comment: Normally the optimizer chooses way better than you can. And an index does not mean the data is stored in memory. Indexes help finding data. You should read about it. I think you don't really understand how they work

Comment: From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-queries.html: "If an index contains all the columns needed for the result set (known as a covering index), the query might be able to avoid reading the table data at all." Since InnoDB indexes are stored in memory (given a sufficiently large memory pool), this means the data is effectively being retrieved from memory.

Comment: Yes - it might. But that is not the actual purpose of an index.

Comment: Sometimes it is, like in this case.

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. So did you read everything in the manual about indexes? "Effectively" means "almost, but *not*, the case"--so it might, and it might not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB indexes are not automatically stored in the buffer pool. They're stored on disk. Both index pages and data pages are stored on disk.

Both index pages and data pages *may* be copied into the buffer pool in memory, depending on whether earlier queries had requested them. But this is not guaranteed.

Actually when I say "data pages" that's really the clustered index, i.e. PRIMARY. InnoDB stores everything as an index. In the case of the PRIMARY/clustered index, each entry includes all the other columns. That effectively makes the PRIMARY index the "data pages." In some databases, they use the term "index-organized table."

When the optimizer chooses your PRIMARY index, it goes without saying that a primary key read will be able to get all the other columns without any further lookups (except for blob/text data that extends over extra pages).

The "Using index" note in the EXPLAIN report only appears when the query reads all the columns it needs from the index, **and** the index is a secondary index (not the PRIMARY).

"Using index" has nothing to do with in-memory vs. read-from-disk. When a page is requested, it'll read from memory if it's in the buffer pool. If it's not in the buffer pool, it'll be copied from disk into the buffer pool, whether it's a PRIMARY or secondary index.

In fact, when the optimizer reports "Using index" it has no knowledge whether all, some, or none of the pages for the respective index are in the buffer pool, or have yet to be loaded from disk. It only knows that it can get all the columns it needs from one secondary index, without reading the clustered index.

---

Re your comment:

Yes, the entire row is in memory, not just the PK.

The buffer pool contains *pages*, exactly like what's on disk. The pages contain two or more rows of data, meaning the PK plus the columns associated with that PK. When the page gets read from disk, a copy of it is made in the buffer pool. There it stays, byte-for-byte a clone of what's on disk.

Queries only read rows stored in pages in the buffer pool. If a requested row isn't yet in memory, the page that holds that row will immediately be read from disk into the buffer pool, then the query proceeds to read it from memory.

Pages may be evicted from the buffer pool if you need other pages from disk and the buffer pool is full. Thus the buffer pool may be much smaller than the total database on disk. Over time, the most-frequently used pages tend to stay in the buffer pool.

Comment: Thanks, that's a super helpful explanation. So, if the PK actually includes all columns, does that mean the entire row (excluding BLOB/TEXT cols) is buffered into memory? I had always thought what was in memory was the PK column(s) and a pointer to the full row on disk.

Comment: Nothing is in memory unless some prior query caused it to be loaded in memory.  This blog post does a great job showing you the specifics with queries you can run to determine what is going on.  https://michael.bouvy.net/blog/en/2015/01/18/understanding-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size/  InnoTop is also a great tool to isolate you from the nitty gritty.  Depending on the nature of your data, the innodb buffer pool is certainly an invaluable asset in optimizing your mysql performance, but it's not a substitute for a caching server like memcached or redis in my experience.